# How to mix pure and impure data in main?

Tags: haskell

Say I wrote a pure function, `f`, whose signature is

```
f :: Int -> Int
```

How can I write the main function in order to display the 1000 first values like this:

```
(1,f(1)), (2,f(2)), ..., (1000,f(1000))?
```

Comment: What’s the “impure” part of this? If `print $ take 1000 $ zip [1..] $ map f [1..]` works, there isn’t really one…

Comment: I guess `print` is ;) - btw: you should make this into an answer minitech

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's pretty succinct (and, in my obviously biased opinion, quite readable) in Haskell:

```
main = print [(x, f x) | x <- [1..1000]]
```

Comment: Can't resist: `main = print $ map ((,) <*> f) [1..1000]`.

Comment: @user3237465 Cool, the rare "reversed" applicative `((,) <*> f) <$> [1..1000]` (the operators being reversed from the usual `f <$> g <*> h` pattern)!

Comment: @Daniel Wagner : ok, but how to get the following behaviour : print (n,f(n)) as soon as it is computed : the behaviour is : compute (1,f(1)), then print (1,f(1)), compute (2,f(2)) and print (2,f(2)) ...etc

Comment: @lolveley That is the default behavior. Ain't laziness great?